# aggregating datetime objects in python to the hour

Tags: python, datetime

I have a list of datetime objects in python and want to aggregate them by the hour.  For example if I have a datetime object for

```
[03/01/2012 00:12:12,
 03/01/2012 00:55:12,
 03/01/2012 01:12:12,
 ...]
```

I want to have a list of datetime objects for every hour along with a count of the number of datetime objects I have that fall into that bucket.  For my example above I would want output of 
`[03/01/2012 00:00:00, 03/01/2012 01:00:00]` in one list and a count of the entries in another list: `[2,1]`.

Answer (score 3):

You could store that kind of data efficiently with a dictionary where the keys are hours and the values are lists of the datetime objects. e.g. (untested):

```
l = [datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.datetime.now()] #...etc.
hour_quantization = {}
for dt in l:
    if dt.hour not in hour_quantization:
        hour_quantization[dt.hour] = [dt]
    else:
        hour_quantization[dt.hour].append(dt)

counts = [len(hour_quantization[hour]) for hour in hour_quantization.keys()]
```

see the [doc entry on datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#module-datetime)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a list of datetime objects, you can count how many of each hour there are:

```
from collections import Counter
hours = [t.hour for t in ts]
Counter(hours)
```

This will give you:

```
Counter({0: 2, 1: 1})
```